# Flask: Heroku with custom domain name breaks sessions?

Tags: python, session, cookies, flask

I have a Flask application hosted on Heroku, and the Heroku instance (say, "`helloworld.herokuapp.com`") has a custom domain name, say "`www.helloworld.com`".

When I access the app at the native heroku URL, sessions work perfectly fine. When I access it at `www.helloworld.com`, they don't work. I assume that this is because the session cookie that Flask is signing is for the wrong domain.

I tried assigning `app.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` and `app.SERVER_NAME` to '`helloworld.com`', but it still only signs the session cookies for `helloworld.herokuapp.com`.

Is there any way I can force the session cookies to sign as my custom domain?

Comment: Add a `.` in front of `helloworld.com` so it becomes `.helloworld.com` for `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` and try it again.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work.

Comment: Is Flask not allowed to set cookies cross domain or something?

Comment: Can you share some code? how are you setting the SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN and SERVER_NAME variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much testing and many permutations of `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` and `SERVER_NAME`, I concluded that the problem was with Heroku. Something about the way Heroku currently routes/hooks up to custom domains breaks domain cookies.

I verified this by moving to EC2...now everything works.